# Flutter video_player plugin getting Uncaught UnimplementedError error on web

Tags: flutter, video-player, uncaught-exception

When I run the flutter app's video page on the web, I get `"Uncaught UnimplementedError: init() has not been implemented."` error.
On iOS or Android there is no error. Even though I initialized the sound to 0 but the result did not change. Where am i doing wrong?

Versions:
`video_player: ^2.6.1`
`chewie: ^1.5.0`

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kindergarten/Models/School/Gallery/gallery_detail_model.dart';
import 'package:kindergarten/Utils/color_palette.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPlayerView extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerView({super.key, required this.model});

  final GalleryDetailModel model;

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerView> createState() => _VideoPlayerViewState();
}

class _VideoPlayerViewState extends State<VideoPlayerView> {
  VideoPlayerController? _videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController? _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initVideoPlayer();
  }

  void _initVideoPlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.model.videoUrl.value);

    await _videoPlayerController
      ?..initialize().then((value) => {
            widget.model.aspectRatio.value = _videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
            setState(() {
              if (kIsWeb) {
                _videoPlayerController?.setVolume(0);
              }
            })
          });

    _chewieController = ChewieController(videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController!, autoPlay: false, allowMuting: true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController?.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _videoPlayerController!.value.isInitialized
        ? Chewie(controller: _chewieController!)
        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: ColorPalette.yellow));
  }
}
```

Even though I initialized the sound to 0 and set auto play to false but the result did not change.